# What is a 4 season greenhouse wall/ceiling made of?

Tags: greenhouse, climate

What material would I want to use to build the walls, and ceiling of for a  4 season greenhouse around the 45N,93W [(4a)](http://www.bachmans.com/Zone-Map/divHomePage.html?categoryCode=02&cnb=ZoneMap)?

Comment: I assume 45N is a latitude. What would help is the temperature range, what you intend to grow, how large a greenhouse, access to water, what surface do you intend?  earth, paving slabs, poured concrete?  Without this information I think this question will be closed as "Too broad"

Comment: Relatively cheap, ultraviolet stabilized plastic greenhouse film. Relatively permanent, double-wall polycarbonate panels. Standard polyethylene only lasts a season so don't bother.

Comment: I'm thinking about using natural sunlight to reduce the requirements for the amount of power needed to have the plants grow cheaper for INDUSTRIAL!!!!!!! aquaponic growing of many different types of plants year round.

Comment: If you're investing heavily in infrastructure, you don't want to rely on natural lighting, but use grow lights instead so that you can grow all  year round.

Comment: @kevinsky is right. We need most of the details he mentions. 45 degrees North latitude could mean anything from the Rocky Mountains in Montana to somewhere in Central France. Both the same latitude, but your growing conditions vary extremely.

Comment: @GardenerJ added the change.

Comment: You are not giving us the information we need to provide a good answer.  See my first comment, answer those questions please

Comment: 45N,93W is the Saint Paul MN area, but I was trying to broaden the question for people who experience 4 real seasons (spring, summer, fall, winter), not  "rainy season", and "dry season".

Comment: I figured out you were saying "add the grow zone".

Comment: I think this question would be fine, if the OP added a few more details. It's great that they added the growing zone, but we also need to know what they intend to grow. If it's a hot house for orchids, you'll need a more insulating material. While you could still consider it broad, because they could technically use saran wrap. I think you could reasonably narrow it down to one or two siding choices appropriate for what they're growing and their grow zone. It might also be helpful to note how much sun it's getting on a typical day. Is it full sun all day or partial shade?