# What type of plastic covering would be good for a heated greenhouse in the winter?

Tags: overwintering, greenhouse

Can anyone tell me their experiences with different plastic coverings for greenhouses.  This year we've built the structure (I've got to get a picture for you) with the vegetable garden growing beneath.  I am getting cross-eyed looking for information on decent plastic to cover this greenhouse through this next winter.  Next year we will use that double layered hard plastic.  But just want a good, CLEAR? plastic to last for this winter.  We'll be heating this structure...last year in October we got a snowfall that collapsed our 'polytunnel'...any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: THis quexstion should be closed as it's a duplicate of: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23656/what-is-a-4-season-greenhouse-wall-ceiling-made-of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They make "overwintering film" (4mil, I think) which is supposed to work for 1 season. I have no experience with it.

I have considerable experience (by now) with 4-year, 6 mil, IR-UV-AntiDrip greenhouse poly, which I think has been typically 11 cents a square foot, and it beats the heck out of using 6 mil untreated builders poly (vapor barrier plastic.)

Attachments are key - you need to attach the film in such a way that the loads are spread out so the plastic does not simply tear out the fasteners. Rolling it around a wooden batten and nailing through the batten, special wiggle-wire channels, there are various means. Using a double layer and inflating the space between is helpful if you can afford ~50 watts of blower 24/7/365.

I've had more trouble with wind ripping it off (see, "attachments!!") than snow loads - it's on 4 foot spacing, metal supports and I have at times wondered about the frame taking the load, but the film sure takes it just fine if it's attached.

Window-like clarity and good greenhouse film do not go hand in hand, from what I understand. Some films are even treated for extra diffusion.

Comment: How much light gets transmitted through this material ?

Comment: Ecnerwal this answer is great...we've been arguing about the attaching stuff...got 4 foot spacing but the peak is a 2X4...What about using composite roofing tiles along the 2X4...how are you attaching the plastic to the frame?  Duct tape and screws...what are you talking about with "attachments".  Yeah, I get the clear and opaque plastic stuff.  Amazingly convoluted.  This is a temporary solution until we can afford the double poly.  Pretty short on electricity here, need to see how much this blower would take.  This is a great start, thank you!!  Is your greenhouse heated?

Comment: I put also a net below the plastic, in order not to have "bowls" caused by heavy rain or snow, which on long term it will damage the plastic.

Comment: Giacomo...where can I look up this 'net'?  Makes sense!

Comment: Ecnerwal, have you seen Solar Ice?  And that batten tape to use to attach the plastic to the wood?